# How can i change the font size of label of node uniformly in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, labels

I want to give nodes a label by `\node [label=below:$1$] {$X$}`. But the size of the label is the same with "X". i want it to be script size. so i can type `\node [label=below:$\scriptstyle 1$] {$X$}`. but the nodes i want to label is not only one. i try the option `\begin{tikzpicture}[commutative diagrams/every label]`. but then `$X$` also becomes script size.

So which option can set the size of label to be script size with holding the size of main node.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand the question, but `every label/.append style={text=red, font=\scriptsize}` works for me.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [every label/.append style={text=red, font=\scriptsize}]
\node[draw, label=label] (A) {node};
\node[draw, label=label,xshift=2cm] (B) {node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update** because of a comment to this answer:

Have a look in the [TikZ documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) chapter 17 Nodes and Edges to get an idea which type of nodes use which styles automatically.

The style `every label` is applied to all label nodes automatically, but not to "normal" nodes on edges. See the following example where the nodes on the edges also get a `label`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every label/.append style={text=red, font=\scriptsize}
  ]
  \node[draw, label=label] (A) {node};
  \node[draw, label=label,xshift=2cm] (B) {node};
  \path(A)edge["$\alpha$"'label=$x$](B);% quotes syntax

  \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
    \node[draw, label=label] (A) {node};
    \node[draw, label=label,xshift=2cm] (B) {node};
    \path(A)edge node[below,label=$x$]{$\alpha$}(B);% basic syntax
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

If all nodes on edges should also be `red` and `\scriptsize` you can add

```
every edge/.append style={nodes={text=red, font=\scriptsize}}
```

to the options for the `tikzpicture`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every label/.append style={text=red, font=\scriptsize},
    every edge/.append style={nodes={text=red, font=\scriptsize}}
  ]
  \node[draw, label=label] (A) {node};
  \node[draw, label=label,xshift=2cm] (B) {node};
  \path(A)edge["$\alpha$"](B);% quotes syntax

  \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
    \node[draw, label=label] (A) {node};
    \node[draw, label=label,xshift=2cm] (B) {node};
    \path(A)edge node[above]{$\alpha$}(B);% basic syntax
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It is also possible to restrict the style change to edge nodes defined by the quotes syntax. This nodes use the style `every edge quotes` automatically:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every label/.append style={text=red, font=\scriptsize},
    every edge quotes/.append style={text=red, font=\scriptsize}
  ]
```

Result:

[image]

---

Note that you can define an own style and add this new style to the node styles you want to change in the same way:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mylabels/.style={text=red, font=\scriptsize},
    every label/.append style={mylabels},
    every edge/.append style={mylabels}
  ]
  \node[draw, label=label] (A) {node};
  \node[draw, label=label,xshift=2cm] (B) {node};
  \path(A)edge["$\alpha$"](B);% quotes syntax

  \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
    \node[draw, label=label] (A) {node};
    \node[draw, label=label,xshift=2cm] (B) {node};
    \path(A)edge node[above]{$\alpha$}(B);% basic syntax
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, it work well. i just want to draw a quiver.  but i have some more questions. i type `\node (1) at (0,0) [label=below:1] {$\circ$};` and `\node (2) at (2,0) [label=below:2] {$\circ$};`. then the `every label/.append style={text=red, font=\scriptsize}` does not apply to `\path[->] (1) edge["$\alpha$"] (2);`. of course, `\path[every label,->]` works. But, i am wonder why the script size does not apply to the label created by `\path` automatically...

Comment: @jiaopjie See my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, i got it. So, it means that, the `every label` just influences the "label" created by the option `label`. But the nodes on the edge are just usual nodes. This is the reason i made a mistake. Thank you very much!!